# Different way of creating account

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts

I have created one account using the command `geth account new` , name acc1 and another under the geth console using the command `personal.newAccount()` name it acc2. Now i am not able to see the acc1 using the command `eth.accounts` and acc2 using the command `geth account list` . 
Both accounts have been created on same node. Then why the data of both accounts have been synchronized between both consoles.
 
What is the difference in both the ways of account creation?

Comment: can you help me create my account in ethereum

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It happens. The reason is the datadir being used for creating the account. for

```
geth account new
```

the default datadir is used is "~/.ethereum/keystore"(it's on my ubuntu OS).

You can go to that directory and see. There shall be one file of format "**UTC--2017-02-13T07-14-57.563336682Z--your account**". this is the account, which gets created when you do

```
geth account new
```

if you're running your private chain using **geth**, then you must have defined your **own datadir** while starting the **geth console**. so, when you do

```
personal.newAccount()
```

it goes into the "**datadir**/keystore".

Now, if you want the account created by

```
geth account new
```

to come under the

```
eth.accounts
```

You simply do **cp** from the "~/.ethereum/keystore" to "datadir/keystore".
you shall be able to see the accounts in the

```
eth.accounts
```

in your console.

Now, if you want that your all future accounts, create using

```
geth account new
```

must be visible when you do

```
eth.accounts
```

in geth console, then you must do this:

```
geth --datadir "**path to your data dir**" account new
```

This shall create all the accounts, as per your private chain datadir. and you shall be able to see all the accounts.

Hope it helps.

Thanks

Comment: Curious about records ```geth account new``` makes on a filesystem. Could you please confirm it is just an encrypted public key, e.g. "UTC--2017-02-13T07-14-57.563336682Z--your account"?