# what does mean signer's key JSON on puppeth sealer?

Tags: private-blockchain

System information
Geth version: 1.8.8-stable-2688dab4
OS & Version: ubuntu

I'm currently created private ethereum network using puppeth, when I created a sealer/ miner, appear this question **"Please paste the signer's key JSON:"**

whats that is mean? and where I can get signer's key JSON?

thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

keystore folder hold keystore file.
signer's key JSON is the encrypted privated key.
[you can generate one](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12824/different-way-of-creating-account)